# killing all non-responding applications with autoit

Tags: windows, autoit, kill-process

How can I automatically close not responding applications with [autoit](http://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/) under windows? These type of applications usually get a title of the form "XXXX (Not Responding)". I tried the following code but without any success:

```
; Wait 10 seconds for the a window to appear.
Local $hWnd = WinWait("Not Responding", "", 10)

; Wait for 2 seconds before calling the WinKill function.
Sleep(2000)

; Kill the window using the handle returned by WinWait.
WinKill($hWnd, "")
```

Comment: I'm assuming the above code executes after a non-responding window is reached. Can you explain further as to what goes wrong when you execute the above code?

Comment: well, the first line is not hit. The script is still waiting till "Not Responding" Application is started, I suppose

Answer (score 2):

Your code is fine, you just need to set WinTitleMatchMode in order to match title substring.

```
Opt("WinTitleMatchMode", 2) ;1=start, 2=subStr, 3=exact, 4=advanced, -1 to -4=Nocase

; Wait 10 seconds for the a window to appear.
Local $hWnd = WinWait("Not Responding", "", 10)

; Wait for 2 seconds before calling the WinKill function.
Sleep(2000)

; Kill the window using the handle returned by WinWait.
WinKill($hWnd, "")
```

Comment: Confirm hit. What a simple an powerful solution to kill not responding windows :)

Comment: You should check right before your Kill call again, whether the title still has the "Not Responding" in it... It might have become responsive again in the meanwhile...

Answer (score 1):

Use this for a test. (Need to put it in a loop, if you want to check every x sec)

```
Opt('WinTitleMatchMode', 2)
Opt('WinSearchChildren', 1)

Local $var = WinList()
Local $s_PID_Buffer
For $i = 2 To $var[0][0]
    If BitAND(WinGetState($var[$i][1]), 2) Then
        ; is visible
        If Not StringInStr($s_PID_Buffer, ";" & WinGetProcess($var[$i][1]) & ";") Then
            ; show PID only once
            $s_PID_Buffer &= ";" & WinGetProcess($var[$i][1]) & ";"
            ConsoleWrite($i & @TAB & "Title=" & $var[$i][0] & @LF & "Handle=" & $var[$i][1] & @CRLF & "PID: " & WinGetProcess($var[$i][1]) & @CRLF & @CRLF)
            If  StringInStr($var[$i][0], 'Not Responding') Then
                ProcessClose(WinGetProcess($var[$i][1]))
                WinKill($var[$i][1])
            EndIf
        EndIf
    EndIf
Next
```

Comment: I find the answer insightful. On my windows 7 machine (I suppose) the `ProcessClose` brutally tries to close the dead process. Then the monitors flash a couple of times, the not responding window trully hangs (that even AutoIt Window Info does give an info) although the process is still there in the task menu. The positive about this is that I trully have a hanged application that I can try to kill :)